# Drinfeld Sokolov and the semiinfinite flag variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-representation-theory, affine-grassmannian

For a long time I've been confused about Drinfeld Sokolov/BRST reduction/semiinfinite cohomology for affine Lie algebras. Most treatments define it in what to me feels like a fairly ad-hoc way, by choosing a nilpotent element then applying an elaborate construction. (Of course it's not unmotivated: it generalises the BRST construction for *finite* dimensional Lie algebras, and in a precise sense it is a quantisation of Hamiltonian reduction of $LN$ acting on a certain subspace of $\widehat{\mathfrak{g}}^*$).

However, until I see a geometric interpretation of what's going on I think I will continue to be confused.

**Question:** is there a "geometric" interpretation of the Drinfeld-Sokolov functor, e.g. one living over the semiinfinite flag variety?

If so, what is the relation to the above remarks in parentheses?

Comment: Have you looked at Frenkel--Ben-Zvi, Vertex algebras and algebraic curves, Chapter 16? I don't have the book at hand but I remember a fairly extensive discussion of Drinfeld Sokolov, likely with some geometric content given the style of the book.

Comment: @Balazs Thanks for the response. Sadly I think in that book they don't actually give any Beilinson-Bernstein geometric explanation. The closest they get is that parenthetical remark about the classical limit being Hamiltonian reduction.

Comment: A very satisfying answer is provided by https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04937. In short, the Drinfeld-Sokolov functor comes from the 2-categorical functor of Whittaker coinvariants, applied to the category of Kac-Moody modules. However, this answer may be too categorical for your taste.

Comment: A more algebraic answer is given by A.2 of the cited paper. Raskin's heuristic explanation is that it is "cohomology along $\mathfrak{n}[[t]]$ and homology along $\mathfrak{n}((t))/\mathfrak{n}[[t]],$ and his definition makes this idea precise. My personal way of thinking about it is that it is "ordinary Lie algebra cohomology for $\mathfrak{n}((t))$, but shifted by $\operatorname{dim}\mathfrak{n}[[t]]$ degrees," which is complete nonsense (because $\mathfrak{n}[[t]]$ is infinite dimensional) but captures its behavior.

Comment: P.S. The semi-infinite flag variety is an important part of this story, but I think for your question specifically it is a red herring. It appears when you think about $LN$ invariants without a twist. With a twist, the relevant geometry is instead that of Whittaker. This might seem like a small difference but it's really not.

Comment: @dhy Thanks. I was aware of the Whittaker construction, so it's your last comment I'm most interested in. So if I understand it correctly you are saying that, although you can localise any $\widehat{\mathfrak{g}}$ module onto a bunch of different spaces $X$ (e.g. the semiinfinite flag variety), this doesn't interact with the Whittaker construction in the sense that there is no natural definition of the Whittaker functor acting on $Dmod(X)$ that isn't just ''consider a D module as a $\widehat{\mathfrak{g}}$ module and apply Whittaker". Is that right?

Comment: @Meow Oh, if that's what you want then you're in luck: Whittaker is actually easier to describe on $D(X)$ than on $\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod}$. I more meant that there's no reason to take $X$ specifically the semi-infinite flag variety.

Comment: @dhy Oh, that's great! Is there anywhere that I can see this written up? The ideal would be that, for a certain choice of $X$, the Whittaker functor on $D(X)$ corresponds to some other functor that is fairly geometric and is not a priori obviously the same as Whittaker (i.e. a "geometric construction which is not obviously the same as Whittaker").

Comment: @Meow Hmm, what is it about Whittaker itself that you don't like? In any case, here is one possible answer: For $X$ the affine flag variety (or the affine grassmannian,) Whittaker is the same as what is called "baby Whittaker," which is what is studied in e.g. Arkhipov-Bezrukavnikov (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0201073).

Comment: @dhy Thanks for this, maybe baby Whittaker is what I'm after. I have no problem with Whittaker, but it is nice to understand things in as many ways as possible, and I've come to expect that often these things have both an algebraic and a geometric interpretation.

Comment: @Meow Well, my confusion is that you seem to be placing Whittaker on the algebraic side, while I think of it as a purely geometric construction.

Comment: @dhy By Whittaker I mean the Whittaker functor as in Arakawa's ``Representation theory of W-algebras''.

Comment: @Meow Aha, OK, that explains it. When I say Whittaker I mean the operation of taking $(LN,\chi)$-equivariant D-modules, defined e.g. in Section 1.13 of the paper of Raskin I linked earlier.

Comment: It might make sense to backtrack and make sure you're happy with the translation between algebraic and geometric interpretation of Whittaker for reductive groups say over C, before loop groups -- as a quantization of the Kostant slice eg, or as studying a twisted form of the cotangent bundle of G/N. The two have natural loop analogs, which are much more technical to make precise (cf Raskin's beautiful work) but morally speaking directly analogous.

Comment: In particular semi infinite flags DO seem to me an important part of the picture geoemtrically, except that we're studying a twisted form of D-modules on them rather than the untwisted one. Then the geometric operation @dhy is discussing is represented by this LG category of "twisted" D-modules on semiinfinite flags

Comment: And a caveat --- the word "twisted"here is slightly different than the standard one in D-module theory -- the Whittaker story is about twisting D-modules on G/N (or its loop version) by a G_a-torsor (character of N) rather than a G_m torsor (hence there are exponential maps around to relate it to more familiar twistings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe let me try to synthesize my comments into an answer. All of this is contained in Raskin's beautiful paper arxiv.org/abs/1611.04937 on Whittaker categories. Convention: We work here in the derived world, i.e., all our categories are assumed pretriangulated dg (equivalently one can take stable $\infty-$categories).

Let $LG$ be the loop group of $G$, considered as a group ind-scheme. Convolution endows the category of D-modules $D(LG)$ with the structure of a monoidal category, and we can consider module categories $C$ for $D(LG)$. Two important examples:

1. The category of D-modules $D(X)$ on an ind-scheme $X$ with a $LG$ action.
2. The category $\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod}$ of representations of the affine Lie algebra.

The $D(LG)$ action on the first example is relatively straightforward to construct, but the second example merits some explanation. The easiest way to see that there should be such an action is to interpret objects $\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod}$ as D-modules on $LG$ weakly equivariant for the left $LG$ action. Such objects are preserved by the right action of $LG$, and this induces the desired action. (Making this precise is very technical, and I will avoid saying more about it.)

More generally, you can include a level here; this is very useful but doesn't alter anything I will say below so I suppress it.

Now take the subgroup $LN$ of $LG$, and choose a nondegenerate character $\chi$ of $LN$, just as you would for Drinfeld-Sokolov. For any category $C$ as above, we define the Whittaker category $\operatorname{Whit}(C)$ to be the category of $(LN,\chi)$-equivariant objects in $C$. More precisely, it is $\operatorname{Hom}_{D(LN)}(\operatorname{Vect},C)$, where the action on $\operatorname{Vect}$ is twisted by $\chi.$ For $C\cong D(X)$, this recovers exactly D-modules on $X$ which are $(LN,\chi)$-equivariant.

There is also a dual construction, which I denote by $\operatorname{Whit}_{co}(C),$ given by Whittaker coinvariants, i.e., $C\otimes_{D(LN)}\operatorname{Vect}.$ Raskin proves in the aforementioned paper that

$$\operatorname{Whit}(C)\cong\operatorname{Whit}_{co}(C).$$

As $\operatorname{Whit}_{co}(C)$ is a category of coinvariants, it comes with a natural functor from $C$. So the equivalence between invariants and coinvariants gives us a natural functor $C\rightarrow\operatorname{Whit}(C)$ as well, which we call !-averaging and denote by $\operatorname{Av}_!$. (For $C=D(X)$ it can be defined explicitly as a $!$-pushforward of D-modules, but it is not a priori obvious that this $!$-pushforward is well defined.)

Now what happens for $C\cong\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod}$?

In this case, there is an equivalence $\operatorname{Whit}(\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod})\cong\mathcal{W}\operatorname{-mod},$ for $\mathcal{W}$ the W-algebra. Furthermore, the functor $\operatorname{Av}_!:\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod}\rightarrow\mathcal{W}\operatorname{-mod}$ is exactly the operation of Drinfeld-Sokolov reduction.

So this provides a geometric interpretation of Drinfeld-Sokolov reduction. Let me give one quick (slightly silly) application of this framework. Denote the affine Grassmannian of $G$ by $\operatorname{Gr}$. Then we have a global sections functor $D(\operatorname{Gr})\rightarrow\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod}.$ Because this functor is $LG$-equivariant, it gives a functor

$$\operatorname{Whit}(D(\operatorname{Gr}))\rightarrow\operatorname{Whit}(\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod})$$

such that the two compositions

$$D(\operatorname{Gr})\rightarrow\operatorname{Whit}(D(\operatorname{Gr}))\rightarrow\operatorname{Whit}(\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod})$$

and

$$D(\operatorname{Gr})\rightarrow\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod}\rightarrow\operatorname{Whit}(\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod})$$

are equivalent. So for any D-module $M$ on $\operatorname{Gr}$, the Drinfeld Sokolov-reduction $\operatorname{DS}(\Gamma(M))$ only depends on the image of $M$ inside $\operatorname{Whit}(\operatorname{Gr})$ (which is a small and pretty well understood category.)

Comment: Thanks, this is a really wonderful answer! I suppose my question about the semiinfinite flag variety might be: is there a special space $X$ with an $\widehat{LG}$ action for which the map $\text{Whit}(D(X))\to\text{Whit}(\hat{g}\text{-mod})$ an isomorphism, or close to one? Basically whether for a certain space $X$ your "slightly silly application" is maximally nice.

Comment: @Meow This is a very deep question, and a bunch of work (not all published) has been done on it for different values of $X$. I don't know of any individual such $X$ that "best approximates" $\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod}$, but by studying the map for different values of $X$ one can learn a huge amount about $\hat{g}\operatorname{-mod}.$ If you name a specific $X$ you are curious about I can tell you what is known (at least at critical level, where the story is a bit more straightforward).

Comment: I'd be very interested in seeing what's been published, especially for the semiinfinite flag variety (or the affine grassmannian, or the affine flag variety). I'm actually interested in non-critical level, but I suppose understanding the critical level will help hugely nonetheless.